# about 'Ask + PREPOSITION + something' and 'Ask something'

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

What's difference between

> I am writing to ask for some information about courses.

and

> I am writing to ask some information about courses.

**cf.**

- Can I **ask a favour** of you?
- Why don't you **ask his advice**?

Comment: The first is good, the second better as **I am writing to ask some questions about courses**.

Answer (score 1):

The verb **ask** differs from similar verbs such as seek and request in that you have to ask someone, either directly or indirectly, even though that *someone* might be a computer or a deity.

When you say:

> Can I ask a favour of you?

you mean: *Can I ask you for a favour?*

and

> Why don't you ask his advice

means: *Why don't you ask him for advice.

Equally, when you say:

> May I ask a question?

It's understand that you are speaking to someone, meaning:

> May I ask you a question (or *a question of you*).

So although it's correct to *seek* or *request* information or answers, it's not correct to *ask information*.

You have to follow *ask* with *for* (or possibly another preposition such as *unto*).